# Umbraco Lucene Index Device not ready

Tags: asp.net-mvc, lucene, umbraco, umbraco7

So I am getting an exception on an Umbraco 7 instance on windows shared hosting. It seems like after an arbitrary amount of time an issue crops up with the Lucene Index (whose API I do not call directly) and the application goes into a state of error until I refresh the app pool. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
2015-08-04 05:57:08,413 [7] ERROR Umbraco.Core.UmbracoApplicationBase 
- [Thread 342] An unhandled exception occurred
System.IO.IOException: The device is not ready.

at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.FileStream.ReadCore(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at System.IO.FileStream.Read(Byte[] array, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at System.IO.BinaryReader.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 index, Int32 count)
   at Lucene.Net.Store.SimpleFSDirectory.SimpleFSIndexInput.ReadInternal(Byte[] b, Int32 offset, Int32 len)
   at Lucene.Net.Store.BufferedIndexInput.Refill()
   at Lucene.Net.Store.BufferedIndexInput.ReadByte()
   at Lucene.Net.Store.IndexInput.ReadVInt()
   at Lucene.Net.Index.TermBuffer.Read(IndexInput input, FieldInfos fieldInfos)
   at Lucene.Net.Index.SegmentTermEnum.Next()
   at Lucene.Net.Index.SegmentTermEnum.ScanTo(Term term)
   at Lucene.Net.Index.TermInfosReader.Get(Term term, Boolean useCache)
   at Lucene.Net.Index.TermInfosReader.Terms(Term term)
   at Lucene.Net.Index.SegmentReader.Terms(Term t)
   at Lucene.Net.Index.DirectoryReader.MultiTermEnum..ctor(IndexReader topReader, IndexReader[] readers, Int32[] starts, Term t)
   at Lucene.Net.Index.DirectoryReader.Terms(Term term)
   at Lucene.Net.Search.WildcardTermEnum..ctor(IndexReader reader, Term term)
   at Lucene.Net.Search.WildcardQuery.GetEnum(IndexReader reader)
   at Lucene.Net.Search.MultiTermQuery.ConstantScoreAutoRewrite.Rewrite(IndexReader reader, MultiTermQuery query)
   at Lucene.Net.Search.WildcardQuery.Rewrite(IndexReader reader)
   at Lucene.Net.Search.BooleanQuery.Rewrite(IndexReader reader)
   at Lucene.Net.Search.BooleanQuery.Rewrite(IndexReader reader)
   at Lucene.Net.Search.IndexSearcher.Rewrite(Query original)
   at Lucene.Net.Search.Query.Weight(Searcher searcher)
   at Lucene.Net.Search.Searcher.CreateWeight(Query query)
   at Lucene.Net.Search.Searcher.Search(Query query, Filter filter, Int32 n, Sort sort)
   at Examine.LuceneEngine.SearchResults.DoSearch(Query query, IEnumerable`1 sortField, Int32 maxResults)
   at Examine.LuceneEngine.Providers.BaseLuceneSearcher.Search(ISearchCriteria searchParams, Int32 maxResults)
   at Examine.LuceneEngine.Providers.BaseLuceneSearcher.Search(ISearchCriteria searchParams)
   at Umbraco.Web.PublishedCache.XmlPublishedCache.PublishedMediaCache.GetUmbracoMedia(Int32 id)
   at Umbraco.Web.PublishedCache.XmlPublishedCache.PublishedMediaCache.GetById(UmbracoContext umbracoContext, Boolean preview, Int32 nodeId)
   at Umbraco.Web.PublishedCache.ContextualPublishedCache`1.GetById(Boolean preview, Int32 contentId)
   at Umbraco.Web.UmbracoHelper.TypedMedia(Object id)
   at ASP._Page_Views_HomePageCarouselItem_cshtml.Execute() in g:\pleskvhosts\crossfitbyob.com\httpdocs\Views\HomePageCarouselItem.cshtml:line 7
   at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy()
   at System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy()
   at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage)
   at System.Web.Mvc.RazorView.RenderView(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer, Object instance)
   at System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerCompiledView.Render(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer)
   at Umbraco.Core.Profiling.ProfilingView.Render(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer)
   at System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper.RenderPartialInternal(String partialViewName, ViewDataDictionary viewData, Object model, TextWriter writer, ViewEngineCollection viewEngineCollection)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Html.PartialExtensions.Partial(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, String partialViewName, Object model, ViewDataDictionary viewData)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Html.PartialExtensions.Partial(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, String partialViewName, Object model)
   at ASP._Page_Views_HomePageCarouselFolder_cshtml.Execute() in g:\pleskvhosts\crossfitbyob.com\httpdocs\Views\HomePageCarouselFolder.cshtml:line 8
   at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy()
   at System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy()
   at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage)
   at System.Web.Mvc.RazorView.RenderView(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer, Object instance)
   at System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerCompiledView.Render(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer)
   at Umbraco.Core.Profiling.ProfilingView.Render(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer)
   at System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper.RenderPartialInternal(String partialViewName, ViewDataDictionary viewData, Object model, TextWriter writer, ViewEngineCollection viewEngineCollection)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Html.PartialExtensions.Partial(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, String partialViewName, Object model, ViewDataDictionary viewData)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Html.PartialExtensions.Partial(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, String partialViewName, Object model)
   at ASP._Page_Views_HomePage_cshtml.Execute() in g:\pleskvhosts\crossfitbyob.com\httpdocs\Views\HomePage.cshtml:line 9
   at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy()
   at System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy()
   at System.Web.WebPages.StartPage.RunPage()
   at System.Web.WebPages.StartPage.ExecutePageHierarchy()
   at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage)
   at System.Web.Mvc.RazorView.RenderView(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer, Object instance)
   at System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerCompiledView.Render(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer)
   at Umbraco.Core.Profiling.ProfilingView.Render(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResult(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass1a.<InvokeActionResultWithFilters>b__17()
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilter(IResultFilter filter, ResultExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass1a.<>c__DisplayClass1c.<InvokeActionResultWithFilters>b__19()
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilter(IResultFilter filter, ResultExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass1a.<>c__DisplayClass1c.<InvokeActionResultWithFilters>b__19()
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass25.<>c__DisplayClass2a.<BeginInvokeAction>b__20()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass25.<BeginInvokeAction>b__22(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<>c__DisplayClass1d.<BeginExecuteCore>b__18(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<>c__DisplayClass8.<BeginProcessRequest>b__3(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End()
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

Comment: Is the site load balanced or hosted on Azure?

Comment: It is not. It is using godaddy shared hosting for windows.

Comment: @JulesMeyer, I'm seeing the same thing, and it's not strictly limited to GoDaddy. There's some more info here (in fact, I linked to your question in my post): https://our.umbraco.org/forum/getting-started/installing-umbraco/20999-Disable-Lucene-Examine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Azure websites uses a remote file system which can cause some havoc with Lucene and we've seen this error quite a few times. I can only assume then that Godaddy also use a remote file server for their IIS websites.

Basically the solution is to run your Umbraco lucene indexes on local temp asp.net storage. In the latest versions of Umbraco (7.2.8+) this functionality is built into the core and you would use the LocalOnly configuration flag for both your indexers and searchers, for example:

```
  <add name="InternalIndexer" type="UmbracoExamine.UmbracoContentIndexer, UmbracoExamine"
       supportUnpublished="true"
       supportProtected="true" 
       analyzer="Lucene.Net.Analysis.WhitespaceAnalyzer, Lucene.Net"
       useTempStorage="LocalOnly"/>

  <add name="InternalSearcher" type="UmbracoExamine.UmbracoExamineSearcher, UmbracoExamine"
       analyzer="Lucene.Net.Analysis.WhitespaceAnalyzer, Lucene.Net" 
       useTempStorage="LocalOnly"/>
```

If you are using old versions of Umbraco you can use a custom library called TempStorage: https://github.com/Shazwazza/UmbracoExamine.TempStorage

This issue has been logged here: http://issues.umbraco.org/issue/U4-3222 but most of the discussion and solution is here: https://our.umbraco.org/forum/getting-started/installing-umbraco/20999-Disable-Lucene-Examine#comment-228320

Comment: Interesting that is the most substantial response I have seen thus far. I am currently on 7.2.4 I believe but that would definitely be worth moving up a couple of minor versions to try out. I let you know how it goes.